# How can i pass a variable between tasks in Azure Devops/VSTS

Tags: azure

For Task 1 I have a CLI task which simply gets the subnet name and subnet ref as below

```
$subnetname1 = az network vnet subnet list --resource-group vnetrg01 --vnet-name vnet01 --query "[].name" -o tsv
$subnetref1 = az network vnet subnet list --resource-group vnetrg01 --vnet-name vnet01 --query "[].id" -o tsv
```

For task 2 I want to deploy an arm template which will use parameters from the pipleine variables in Azure Devops
So for example the result of $subnetref1 in Task 1 above needs to populate the pipleline variable for subnetref (which is setup as a variable in the pipleine) which will then be passed to the arm template  override parameters

cant seem to get this working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with Powershell command,

In the first PowerShell task set the variable as environment variable:

```
$subnetname1 =  az network vnet subnet list --resource-group vnetrg01 --vnet-name vnet01 --query "[].name" -o tsv 
Write-Host $subnetname1
Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=subnetname1;]$subnetname1")
```

In the second task read the variable in this way:

```
$subnetname1 =  $env:subnetname1
Write-Host $subnetname1
```

Comment: What if the task is `bash script` instead of `powershell`?