# How do I set a bash variable in AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to capture Azure Pipeline $(System.AccessToken) and encode it in this pipeline to allow NPM install to authenticate to my feed in Azure DevOps.

```
trigger:
- main

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
- group: Docker-Environment
- name: tag
  value: '$(Build.BuildId)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool: Docker
    workspace:
      clean: all
     
    steps:
    - bash: |
       NPM_PASS_SYS= printf "%s"":$(System.AccessToken)" | base64 # This looks Ok
      env:
       NPM_SYSTEM_TOKEN: "$NPM_PASS_SYS"
      displayName: ECHO NPM_PASS_SYS VAR
    
    - bash: |
       echo $NPM_SYSTEM_TOKEN #EMPTY with $NPM_SYSTEM_TOKEN and $(NPM_SYSTEM_TOKEN)
      displayName: "Echo the variable"
    
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Building the image
      inputs:
        command: build
        repository: $(IMAGE_NAME)
        dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
        containerRegistry: 'DockerRegistryServiceConnection'
        arguments: '--no-cache --build-arg NPM_USER=$(NPM_USER) --build-arg NPM_PASS=$(NPM_PASS_SYS)'
        tags: |
          $(tag)

    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Push to Azure Registry
      inputs:
        command: push
        repository: $(IMAGE_NAME)
        containerRegistry: 'DockerRegistryServiceConnection'
        tags: |
          $(tag)
      name: 'push'
      
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
           docker image rm $(docker image ls -aq) || true
           docker builder prune -f --filter "until=24h"
      displayName: 'Clean old images'
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          rm -rf $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
      displayName: 'Clean sources directory'
```

`NPM_PASS_SYS= printf "%s"":$(System.AccessToken)" | base64` actually prints the output to the Azure DevOps console but echoing the `NPM_PASS_SYS` always returns an empty string.

I already granted my project build service in the organization contributor access to the feed.

Comment: `This question already has an answer here` : No, that is not answered at target link. That answer pertains to Powershell, **NOT BASH**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your YAML Sample, you use the format: `NPM_PASS_SYS= printf "%s"":$(System.AccessToken)" | base64`  to set the variable in bash task.

In Pipeline, bash tasks are separate processes. When you set a variable with the current format, it only applies to the current task.

It cannot be passed to the next task.

On the other hand, the `env` field in bash task is used to pass the variable to current task script instead of set the variable of Pipeline.

To solve this issue, you need to define the variable with the following format: `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputVa]this is the value"`

Here is a YAML example: you can use the script: `NPM_PASS_SYS=$(printf "%s"":$(System.AccessToken)" | base64 -w 0)` to convert the token to base64 format.

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build

     
    steps:
    - bash: |
       NPM_PASS_SYS=$(printf "%s"":$(System.AccessToken)" | base64 -w 0)
       echo $NPM_PASS_SYS
       echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NPM_SYSTEM_TOKEN]$NPM_PASS_SYS"
      displayName: ECHO NPM_PASS_SYS VAR
    
    - bash: |
       echo $(NPM_SYSTEM_TOKEN)
      displayName: "Echo the variable"
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Define variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch)

**Result:**

[image]